# For which $a$ does it hold that $a^2=a^{10}$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$ ?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I want to find the values of $a$ such that $a^2=a^{10}$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$.

For $a\neq 0$ it holds that $a^8=1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$.

We have that $\left (a^4\right )^2=1$, which means that $a^4=\pm 1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$, or not?

So we get $a^4=1$ and $a^4=-1\equiv 10\pmod {11}$.

Is everything correct so far? Do we continue in that way till the power is $1$ ?

Comment: Yes, but you are missing an important point. If $a^8=1$ what does this tell you about the order of $a$ (there are 4 possible values) ? Since the multiplicative group $\mathbb{Z}_{11}^*$ has 10 members how does this restrict the possible order of $a$ ?

Comment: Ah ok!! Thank you!! :-) @gandalf61

Answer (score 4):

$(\Bbb Z/11\Bbb Z)^\times \cong C_{10}$, so if $a^8 = 1$ then $a^2 = 1$, so $a = \pm 1$.

Together with the solution $a=0$ we obtain three solutions.

Comment: Why are the solutions of $a^8=1$ the same as the slutions of $a^2=1$ ?

Comment: The order of $a$ must divide both $8$ and $10$, since $10$ is the order of the group.

Comment: I see!! Thank you so much!! :-)

Answer (score 2):

It holds for $a=0$. Suppose $a\ne0$; then $a^{10}=1$ (Euler-Fermat).

Comment: I see!! Thank you very much!! :-)